# Back-Front Navigation AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have been trying to create a grid where a user clicks on a thumbnail, it will direct him to a specific page with images,description etc.

Now, I want to add two navigation buttons where the user can go to the next project or the previous without having to go back to the homepage (grid).

So far I have managed to create this one (check the plunker link)by googling on how to do this, and now I'm stuck.

Inside the home.html I have created two links.
**#example1.html -> Go to Example 1**
**example2.html -> Go to Example 2**

If you click on "example2.html" it directs you to the correct page but the navigation doesn't work.
If you click on #example1.html it directs you to the example1 but the navigation works, if you put #example2.html it gets you again to the example1.html, which means the  is not correct.

So what should I do when the user for example wants to click the second link and the navigation take him from there?

I am new in Angular so please excuse me if this question seems a bit "noobish".

Comment: I forgot to post the plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/oUw3qW?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question completely. Looks like you want the navigation's back and forward buttons to work. Hopefully this answers your question.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wXnKoL?p=preview

Here are the changes I made:

app.js

```
goBack: function() {
  window.history.back(); //let browser handle the back action
}
```

home.html

```
GRID
<a href="#/example1">Go to Example 1</a> //the url should be the route name and not the html file name
   <a href="#/example2">Go to Example 2</a>
```

routes:

```
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }).
  when('/example1', {  //renamed it to example1 to match #/example1
    templateUrl: 'example.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  }).
  when('/example2', {//renamed it to example2 to match #/example2
    templateUrl: 'example2.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  }).
  when('/example3', {
    templateUrl: 'example3.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  });
```

Comment: Hi Henry,
Thank you very much for the feedback.
Although if you click on the "Example 2" it redirects you to the example1.
That is my issue, something is wrong with the links. If I click to see the Example 2, the navigation should take it from there.

Comment: route name should match the href="#<routename>"

Comment: Thank you very much Henry!
I appreciate the support!!